# Why is this bitwise operation not working?

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

Ok this is probably something really stupid, but I can't understand why this isn't working;

```
    byte temp = (byte)0x80;
    System.out.println(temp);
    byte holder = (byte)(temp | 0x40);
    System.out.println(holder);
```

Produces:

-128

-64

Shouldn't a bitwise or on:

10000000

01000000

Yield

11000000

or -192?

Comment: Then shouldn't 10000000 yield -0?

Comment: The first bit isn't exactly the sign.  The first bit is -128.

Comment: @Natecat that's not the way to work it out, although you happen to get the right number in this case. 11000001 isn't -65, even though 1000001 is 65.

Answer (score 3):

`0x80` represent 128 and `0x40` represent 64. If you print `0x80 | 64` it will output 192.

When you cast to byte `128` becomes `-128` as 128 is higher then `Byte.MAX_VALUE` which is 127.

So the expression you evaluate is `-128 | 64`, while you were probably expecting `128 | 64`, and will result in your output, `-64`.

Comment: "When you cast to byte 128 becomes -128 and 64 becomes -64." is very interesting .can you explain how ?

Comment: @KickButtowski 64 does not becomes -64, it was a typo in my first post. As for 128 becoming -128, it is because 128 overflow Byte.MAX_VALUE as I explained in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing them out this way instead:

`byte b1 = (byte)0x80;
        String s1 = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b1 & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
        System.out.println(s1);
        byte b2 = (byte)0x40;
        String s2 = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b2 & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
        System.out.println(s2);
        byte b3 = (byte)(b1 | b2);
        String s3 = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b3 & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
        System.out.println(s3);`